# Photoshop vector line

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I use the line tool in Photoshop, it creates a ***vector*** layer mask with the shape of that line. When I draw a curved line with the pen tool, the only option I see for making a line out of the path is "Stroke path", which is ***not*** vector (raster).

How do I create a vector line/curve with the pen tool in Photoshop (CS4)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The "pen tool" is not used to create shapes or vectors it is used to create complex paths useful for making selections. If you want more flexibility with vector objects you need Adobe Illustrator not Adobe Photoshop.

Essentially

Illustrator = Vector Images

Photoshop = Photographs

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop's vector capabilities don't go that far, but you can export the paths you made to Illustrator by going to `File > Export > Paths to Illustrator`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to make a vector line or stroke in Photoshop CS4. You can import Vector images into Photoshop, but if you want to edit it in Photoshop, you will have to rasterize the image. I think you can create vector strokes and lines in the newer Photoshop CC versions but sorry it is not possible in CS4.

If you need to make a Vector line or stroke on your already existing vector file, I suggest using a vector software like Illustrator.